# Angular Kendo: have specific url for each tab of tabstrip

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-tabstrip

I want kendo tabstrip (in Angular 2+) to have a specific url for each tab, so that when I click the tab, the url changes and when I enter the url manually, the tabstrip is switched to the desired tab. I can do it in a page holding the tabstrip using the tabstrip.**selectTab** method and the tabstrip.**tabSelect** event, but I must find out the tab index in a rather complicated way. I'd prefer to customize the tabstrip to do it automatically, without any code on a page.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried setting up routes in your router for the tabs?

Comment: The tabs have no url by themself, only the page holding the tabstrip. So I must emulate somehow the url of the tab (e.g. I give the name 'details' to the tab and when the url ends with 'details' I switch to this tab)